# OnCreateView Called twice

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, android-activity, xamarin

I'm trying to create an activity with two tabs, one holding `FragmentA` and one holding `FragmentB`. Here is how I add the fragments to the Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "My App")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ConnectionMenu);
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        AddTab("A", new FragmentA());
        AddTab("B", new FragmentB());
    }

    private void AddTab(string tabText, Fragment fragment)
    {
        var tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(tabText);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.FragmentTransaction.Replace(
                Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, 
                fragment);
        };
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }
}
```

When I rotate the orientation I want to keep fields filled out in the fragments the same. I save my data in `OnSaveInstanceState` and restore the data in `OnActivityCreated`. However, I'm noticing that the `OnCreateView` and `OnActivityCreated` methods are being called twice per rotate. The first time containing my filled in `Bundle` and the second time with bundle being null.

I assume that my error is in the `MyActivity` class but if you need more information let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue. as @JonDouglas said you need to make sure the tab wasn't already loaded before creating a new fragment. To do this the fragment can be loaded from the `FragmentManager` class using a tag. During the `TabSelected` event if the fragment was not previously create, a new fragment is created and added to the event `FragmentTransaction` using the tag. During the `TabUnselected` event, if the fragment was created then it is detached.

I also added in a `Bundle` value to hold onto the last active tab.

Here is the code I used to solve the issue.

```
[Activity(Label = "My App")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ConnectionMenu);
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        AddTab("A", "a_fragment", () => new FragmentA());
        AddTab("B", "b_fragment", () => new FragmentB());
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            var selectedTab = savedInstanceState.GetInt(
                "ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex", 0);
            ActionBar.SetSelectedNavigationItem(selectedTab);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.PutInt(
            "ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex",
            ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex);
    }

    private void AddTab<TFragment>(
        string tabText, 
        string tag,
        Func<TFragment> ctor) where TFragment : Fragment
    {
        var tab = ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(tabText);
        tab.SetTag(tag);
        var fragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag<TFragment>(tag);
        tab.TabSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (fragment == null)
            {
                fragment = ctor.Invoke();
                e.FragmentTransaction.Add(
                    Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, 
                    fragment, 
                    tag);
            }
            else
            {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Attach(fragment);
            }
        };
        tab.TabUnselected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (fragment != null)
            {
                e.FragmentTransaction.Detach(fragment);
            }
        };
        ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you create the fragment in your `Activity.OnCreate()`, you will always have 2 calls due to creating new ones in the method, and maintaining the old ones in the `base.OnCreate()`. What you should probably do is instead of always creating these fragments, you can search via a tag or ID for an existing fragment and use those in the Tabs instead.

i.e.

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ConnectionMenu);
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            AddTab("A", new FragmentA());
            AddTab("B", new FragmentB());
        }
        else 
        {
            Fragment a = (FragmentA)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("my_tag_a");
            Fragment b = (FragmentB)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("my_tag_b");
            AddTab("A", a);
            AddTab("B", b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do I add those tags? somewhere in the axml?

Comment: Yes you can add `android:tag` to your layout `.xml/.axml`.

Comment: As a side note, if you don't want to use tags, just use ID and the `FindFragmentByID` method. Either way should work fine.

Comment: Usually you will use `FindFragmentById` for fragments that provide some type of UI in your layout. `FindFragmentByTag` is typically for fragments that might be containers and not necessarily provide UIs.

Comment: I cant find `SupportFragmentManager` in the `Activity`. Do I need to inherit something else?

Comment: Use regular `FragmentManager`.

Comment: I'm getting back null entries from the `FindFragmentById` and `Tag` methods. Added the tags to the main element in the fragment layout xml files. not sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to solve the issue! :)